# Why isn't float:left working?

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-table, html-email

I'm trying to create a mobile responsive email, but it seems that `float:left` isn't working. I need a set of fresh eyes to take a look at it:

http://scratchpad.io/silent-science-7546

```
       <table id="Flagmark_Headline" class="full_TD_width" height="85" width="551" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="21" height="85" class="mhide"></td>
              <td align="left" valign="top" style="" class="headline" width="365">
                <table border="0" width="365" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="30" class="main_headline" style="font-size: 150%;">
                        <h1 style="padding:0; margin:0;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; font-weight:normal;" size="5">This, is a great headline</font></h1>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="20"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; font-weight:normal;" size="4">No if, ands, or maybes!</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="15"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td class="mhide" width="45"></td>
              <td width="113" class="get-one-hundred">
                <table border="0" bordercolor="" width="113" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="123" height="5"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="get-money" width="123" height="55"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; font-weight:normal;" size="6">?????</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td height="13"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; font-weight:normal;" size="2">Profit</font></font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="551" height="5"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td width="6"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

My CSS:

```
   td[class=headline], td[class=main_headline], td[class=headline] table, td[class=get-one-hundred], td[class=get-money], td[class=get-one-hundred] table, td[class=divider]{width:300px !important; clear: left !important; float: left !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important;}  

   table[id=Flagmark_Headline] { width: 298px !important; }

   table[id=Flagmark_Headline] { padding-bottom: 5px !important; }
```

I tried float:clear, overflow:hidden etc but I'm still stuck! Can anyone help me out?

Comment: what email client are you trying to open this in? A lot of advanced CSS options are ignored by email clients in general. Have a look at this list and see what works: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: This is specifically for iOS and Android, the desktop version is already developed and tested. The mail clients on iOS and Android (thankfully) accept more modern CSS attributes

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted for a simple question?

Comment: according to the list on campaignmonitor android doesn't accept style sheets, or style elements in the header. You will need to put inline styles on your elements I reckon, which for email is probably better anyway as it targets the most clients. I don't see float in that list. However since you are using table cells etc anyway, why not use the ALIGN="left" property? I know these at least work.

Comment: I downvoted it because your example link shows nothing. Your CSS is unreadable in its current form, you have a huge HTML table. You don't show how it doesn't work or what you expect it to do. Lastly, you don't make it possible for us to test any of this easily. To me it shows a lack of effort. Had you dug into this problem yourself, I'm sure you could have reduced the amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. In that process, you might even have solved it yourself. If that wasn't the case, I'd probably have upvoted you instead. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Float is poorly supported in email clients.  I don't even bother using it when coding emails.  One major problem you'll run into when coding responsive emails is the lack of support for max-width in half the versions of Outlook.  To get around this problem I suggest coding your emails to be a static size, say 600px wide, and then adding a media query or two in the head to adjust the size of your elements.  Since you're targeting specifically iOS and Android, both of which support document level media queries, you should be good to go.  You'll have a responsive email in the clients you're targeting and then gracefully degrade down to a static but still good looking email for everyone else.

Comment: Agreed. After doing email for a couple weeks I realized I can't think about it the same way I do e